# How can you remove the Profile fields from mantis

Tags: issue-tracking, mantis

I would like to remove the **Select Profile** and all it's accompanying fields from Mantis issue tracking system when I create or view issues as these are irrelevant to any issues I would like to create.

These include the Platform, OS and OS version fields as well that accompany the profile section.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered on the mantis support forum.  You can do this by entering

```
$g_enable_profiles = OFF;
```

into the config_inc.php file.  If the file does not exist you can create one in your root web directory i.e.

```
<?php
$g_enable_profiles = OFF;
?>
```